# OwinStartupAttribute issue/OWIN Startup Class Missing

Tags: class, asp.net-web-api, owin, startup, katana

No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config. To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

this one is work for everyone,i have tried others like owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false  but didnt work.Below is the final way

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="owin:HandleAllRequests" value="true"/>
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: You *could* also just add the OwinStartup attribute at assembly-level and point it at your Startup class.